# How to solve return outside function in Django

Tags: django, try-except

I have this code but it displays `return outside function` error

Am I doing something wrong. How do I fix it?

```
class vote(request,question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice']) except (KeyError, Choice.DoesnotExist):
        return render(request,'polls/detail.html', { 'question':question, 'error_message':"You didn't select a choice.",})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes +=1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results',args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: Is the `except` placed at the right of the `selected_choice`?

Answer (score 3):

return statements are exclusive to functions.

you should change  `class vote`to `def vote`